# How to show documentation of standard C++ commands on mouse hover in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I'm a student of Mechanical Engineering, so not a big programmer. I'm using Eclipse to get into the deal.II finite element library.

After I got the setup working, Eclipse shows me documentation for every function/class/ect of deal.II on mouse-hover, which is very helpful. I'm relatively new to programming though, so I would like it to do the same for basic C++ commands like, say, `break;` or `unsigned int`.

At the moment I just google everything I don't know, but if possible I'd like an option that works inside of Eclipse and doesn't force me to leave it.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't  have a setting for this. If it is available at all, it would be in a plugin. I know there are plugins for standard libraries like `POSIX` but I don't know of any that provide basic language explanations. You would need to google it.

Comment: @Galik Well, I HAVE googled it of course. Dunno if there's something to find, but I for sure didn't.